# Assume: (C∧D)∨(¬C∧D); Prove: C↔D

Tags: logic, fitch

Is it possible to prove this formally in fitch?
I found that when C is false and D is true the conclusion is false while the premise is true.

Comment: Correct: the argument is *invalid*; thus you cannot prove it.

Comment: However, it is possible to prove `(C∧D)∨(¬C∧¬D)` entails `C↔D`   @SparrowTree